# Reusable TextField in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm using a reusable TextField in Material UI in React and i have a problem using a condition. I need not to use `InputLabelProps` if it isnt passed on to it.

Pls check my reusable TextField below

```
    <TextField
      fullWidth
      type={prop.type}
      label={prop.label}
      name={prop.name}
      variant="outlined"
      value={prop.value}
      onChange={prop.handleChange}
      onBlur={prop.onBlur}
      helperText={prop.helperText}
      error={prop.error}
     {prop.InputLabelProps ? InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: prop.InputLabelProps,
      }} : ''}
    />
```

Comment: @Jayce444. Great! Thanks. Pls put that as an answer

Comment: alrighty, added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set it to undefined if it's not present:

```
InputLabelProps={prop.InputLabelProps ? { shrink: prop.InputLabelProps } : undefined}.
```

If you set a prop to undefined in most cases it'll act like you didn't pass it at all

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a conditional statement, before the ternary operator,

```
     {prop.InputLabelProps && prop.InputLabelProps ? InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: prop.InputLabelProps,
      }} : ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if that syntax works. What you can do is pass an undefined value if your condition didn't match like below:

```
<TextField
      fullWidth
      type={prop.type}
      label={prop.label}
      name={prop.name}
      variant="outlined"
      value={prop.value}
      onChange={prop.handleChange}
      onBlur={prop.onBlur}
      helperText={prop.helperText}
      error={prop.error}
      InputLabelProps=
      {
        props.InputLabelProps 
        ? { shrink: props.InputLabelProps } 
        : undefined
      }
    />
```