# Inline InputLabelProps ternary

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui, jsx

I am humbly asking how do build this without creating a ternary for all inputLabel props when foo exists, and when foo doesn't exist. in this case foo is if we're passing characterLimit into our custom textfield component.

This is essentially what I want, but for multiple props: [Reusable TextField in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64021114/reusable-textfield-in-react)

Here's my code, is there a way to do this conditional inline rather than creating multiple instances of inputLabelProps?

```
import React, {ChangeEvent, useState} from 'react';
import {TextFieldProps, TextField, makeStyles, Box, FormHelperText} from '@material-ui/core';

export interface SATextFieldProps {
  hasWhiteFields?: boolean;
  requiredError?: string | undefined;
  showCharacterCount?: boolean;
  characterLimit?: number;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: any) => ({
  whiteTextField: {
    background: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
}));

export const SATextField = (props: TextFieldProps & SATextFieldProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [characterCount, setCharacterCount] = useState<number>(0);

  const onChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    props.onChange && props.onChange(event);
    props.showCharacterCount && setCharacterCount(event.target.value.length);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        {...props}
        label={props.label}
        id={props.id}
        name={props.name}
        className={props.className}
        type="text"
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth
        inputRef={props.inputRef}
        InputLabelProps={props.InputLabelProps}
        inputProps={{...props.inputProps, props.characterLimit ? {maxLength: props.characterLimit} : undefined, ...{className: classes.whiteTextField}}}
        error={props.error}
        helperText={props.helperText}
        autoComplete={props.autoComplete || 'none'}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      {props.showCharacterCount && (
        <Box position="relative" top="-20px" display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end">
          <FormHelperText
            error={props.error}
          >{`${characterCount} / ${props.characterLimit}`}</FormHelperText>
        </Box>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code instead of posting an image.

Comment: Sorry about that, here is my code in print

Comment: I think you don’t need the ternary at all because it should be okay to pass undefined.  You can just spread it all together with maxLength: props.characterLimit etc.